# Is session replication a part of Java EE standard

Tags: jakarta-ee, session-replication

I'm wondering whether session replication between application servers is a part of official EE standard? I can't find anything about it so providing a link to official documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: I always thought it was part of the app server (e.g. JBoss).

Comment: @user1389596 Yes. But every application server has certain features, which are required to be certified as full fledged Java EE Application Server. They are described in JSR and other places. I'm wondering whether it's part of it or every server implemented it on it's own and thus you can write JEE App Server which do not have such feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *not exactly*. See, in the latest version of the [JavaEE specification](https://java.net/downloads/javaee-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec_EDR.pdf) (under the Servlet 3.1 section), there are several mentions of *Distributable Web Applications* From the specification:

> > **The Servlet specification defines distributable web applications**. To support 
> >     Java EE applications that are distributable, this specification adds the following 
> >     requirements...
>
> **Web containers must support Java EE distributable web applications placing 
>   objects of any of the following types (when supported by the Java EE product) 
>   into a javax.servlet.http.HttpSession** object using the setAttribute or 
>   putValue methods:
>
> > - java.io.Serializable
> > - javax.ejb.EJBObject
> > - javax.ejb.EJBHome
> > - javax.ejb.EJBLocalObject ...

It also goes on to say

> > A web container 
> >     that supports multi-VM operation must ensure that, **when a session is moved from 
> >     one VM to another, all objects of supported types are accurately recreated on the 
> >     target VM.**

While it may be somewhat ambiguous, I can deduce from all the above that a distributable web applications (read: distributed session objects/session replication) is part of the specification

Comment: Great answer. This part of document definitely says that session between clustered machines IS part of standard. However it's not specified how it has to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

No, session replication is not part of the official Java EE as far as I know. There is not a word about session replication requirement in Sevlet or JSP specification. You may have certified Java EE server, which could be a stand alone and then it doesn't need session replication at all. However all vendors that offer clustered solutions have such mechanism implemented, although implementation specifics may vary (e.g. replication via database, memory to memory communication, etc.)